# Apache Ignite Data Seggregation

Tags: .net-core, ignite

I have an application that creates persistent caches on a fixed region (`MYAPP_REGION`) with fixed cached names (`MyApp.Data.Class1`, `MyApp.Data.Class2`, ...etc.)
I am deploying 2 instances of this application for 2 different customers, but they use the same ignite clusters.

What is the correct way to discriminate the data between the instances: do I change the cache name to be by customer or a region per customer is enough?

In a rdbms scenario, we would create 2 different databases; so I am wondering how we would achieve the same thing when using ignite as storage solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you have mentioned, there are a variety of options. If it's only logical division and you are OK with resource sharing, just like with a regular RDBM, then use multiple caches/tables or different [SQL schemas](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/schemas). Keep in mind the desired data distribution and the amount of caches/tables per customer. I.e. if you have 3 nodes and 3 customers with about the same amount of data, most likely you'd like to use a [custom affinity function](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/affinity-collocation) to make them collocated on a single node, but it's a bit different question.

If you want more physical division, for example, if one of the customers needs more resources or special features like native persistence, then it's better to follow the different regions approach which might end up having separate clusters though.